# MessageBox.Show() Custom Icon?

Tags: c#, .net, icons, messagebox

I want to use a custom icon in `MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MeesageBoxIcon.myIcon)` Method.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote one a little while ago, it works exactly like the regular messagebox class.

**CustomMessageBox (Class): http://pastebin.com/m8evBmZi**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class CustomMessageBox
{
    public static DialogResult Show(string Text, string Title, eDialogButtons Buttons, Image Image)
    {
        MessageForm message = new MessageForm();
        message.Text = Title;

        if (Image.Height < 0 || Image.Height > 64)
            throw new Exception("Invalid image height. Valid height ranges from 0 to 64.");
        else if (Image.Width < 0 || Image.Width > 64)
            throw new Exception("Invalid image width. Valid width ranges from 0 to 64.");
        else
        {
            message.picImage.Image = Image;
            message.lblText.Text = Text;

            switch (Buttons)
            {
                case eDialogButtons.OK:
                    message.btnYes.Visible = false;
                    message.btnNo.Visible = false;
                    message.btnCancel.Visible = false;
                    message.btnOK.Location = message.btnCancel.Location;
                    break;
                case eDialogButtons.OKCancel:
                    message.btnYes.Visible = false;
                    message.btnNo.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case eDialogButtons.YesNo:
                    message.btnOK.Visible = false;
                    message.btnCancel.Visible = false;
                    message.btnYes.Location = message.btnOK.Location;
                    message.btnNo.Location = message.btnCancel.Location;
                    break;
                case eDialogButtons.YesNoCancel:
                    message.btnOK.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }

            if (message.lblText.Height > 64)
                message.Height = (message.lblText.Top + message.lblText.Height) + 78;

            return (message.ShowDialog());
        }
    }

    public enum eDialogButtons { OK, OKCancel, YesNo, YesNoCancel }
}
```

**MessageForm (Form): http://pastebin.com/jawHZDzY**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal partial class MessageForm : Form
{
    internal MessageForm() => InitializeComponent();

    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;

    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        DialogResult = DialogResult.No;

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

**MessageForm (Designer Code): http://pastebin.com/CRXjeUFN**

```
partial class MessageForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.picImage = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.lblText = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.btnYes = new Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton();
        this.btnNo = new Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton();
        this.btnCancel = new Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton();
        this.btnOK = new Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picImage)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        //
        // picImage
        //
        this.picImage.ErrorImage = null;
        this.picImage.InitialImage = null;
        this.picImage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 15);
        this.picImage.Name = "picImage";
        this.picImage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 64);
        this.picImage.TabIndex = 0;
        this.picImage.TabStop = false;
        //
        // lblText
        //
        this.lblText.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.lblText.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85, 15);
        this.lblText.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(294, 0);
        this.lblText.Name = "lblText";
        this.lblText.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(28, 13);
        this.lblText.TabIndex = 0;
        this.lblText.Text = "Text";
        //
        // btnYes
        //
        this.btnYes.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.btnYes.FocusDuesEnabled = false;
        this.btnYes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(139, 88);
        this.btnYes.Name = "btnYes";
        this.btnYes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnYes.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnYes.Text = "Yes";
        this.btnYes.Tooltip = "";
        this.btnYes.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnYes.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnYes_Click);
        //
        // btnNo
        //
        this.btnNo.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.btnNo.FocusDuesEnabled = false;
        this.btnNo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 88);
        this.btnNo.Name = "btnNo";
        this.btnNo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnNo.TabIndex = 3;
        this.btnNo.Text = "No";
        this.btnNo.Tooltip = "";
        this.btnNo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnNo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnNo_Click);
        //
        // btnCancel
        //
        this.btnCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.btnCancel.FocusDuesEnabled = false;
        this.btnCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(301, 88);
        this.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel";
        this.btnCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnCancel.TabIndex = 1;
        this.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        this.btnCancel.Tooltip = "";
        this.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCancel_Click);
        //
        // btnOK
        //
        this.btnOK.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.btnOK.FocusDuesEnabled = false;
        this.btnOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 88);
        this.btnOK.Name = "btnOK";
        this.btnOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnOK.TabIndex = 4;
        this.btnOK.Text = "OK";
        this.btnOK.Tooltip = "";
        this.btnOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnOK.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOK_Click);
        //
        // MessageForm
        //
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(394, 129);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnYes);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnNo);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.picImage);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblText);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnOK);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "MessageForm";
        this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(15);
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Title";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picImage)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    internal Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton btnCancel;
    internal Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton btnNo;
    internal Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton btnYes;
    internal Dark.WinForms.Controls.dButton btnOK;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picImage;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.Label lblText;
}
```

Comment: hmmm... is that so? :) I was thinking that somewhere I will just do "Add new image" and voila, but that's one real work to do :) well I have now chance to do some custom stuff, read and understand your code for a while to get grasp of it...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't override this behavior of `MessageBox`. The solution is either use some custom message box, check [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog), or implement your own `MessageBoxForm` and add your custom settings to it, check [this](http://www.techlicity.com/blog/dotnet-creating-a-custom-messagebox.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Task Dialog Indirect API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft, which will help you to show custom dialogs.

Comment: If you were Rube Goldberg perhaps, otherwise I'd probably just create my own Form...

Comment: @Ed S Why should re invent wheel, if there is an API available it is easy to use that right, instead of creating a new one :)

Comment: I don't think using PInvoke here is warranted.  This is not reinventing the wheel, this is more like reinventing the... paper clip.  A simple task.

Comment: @EdS.- I know what you're saying, but using a system control (vs. rolling your own) has some advantages that are easy to overlook. There's a LOT of functionality that you don't normally think about (e.g. behavior with screen readers, behavior with accessibility options, etc). You can _approximate_ it easily on your own, but you may find more and more cases where yours doesn't behave like the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly change an icon of MessageBox so I googled it and I found the solution for that. we can change an icon of message box using window hook.

Hear is the MSDN Magazine link.

[MSDN on the Internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120817123335/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188920.aspx)