# Override WinForms MessageBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, overriding

All, I understand that for extensively customised dialogs I would need to create my own form and `ShowDialog()`. However, in my current case I would just like to extend the MessageBox class to facilitate a `CustomMessageBox` that is capable of showing different icons insted of those determined by the system.

I have not overridden such a control before and I am not even sure where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MessageBox.Show() Custom Icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560493/messagebox-show-custom-icon)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MessageBox` is not a *control* actually (doesn't inherit from `Control`), it's just a class.

Actually, it's even almost a `static` class, as there is no public/protected constructor defined, and only `static` methods. It's more like a factory.

You probably should write your own, as it's not extendable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize MessageBox like that, unfortunately. You will have to roll-your-own.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBox` does not support customization beyond changing the message, caption, and the standard buttons that are available. If you want a custom message box, you have to create one yourself. See [How to create a custom MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932792/56778) for an example.