# MessageBoxIcon as image in PictureBox

Tags: c#, icons, picturebox, messagebox

I want to standardize the look of icons in my app. I have `XtraMessageBox` with standard error icon `MessageBoxIcon.Error` and I want to put exactly the same icon in one of my `PictureBox`.

I searched online on DevEx support and found that they use `SystemIcons` and that I should load it directly but when I do it I don't get the same icon. It looks like `MessageBoxIcon` show me Windows10 error icon and loading the `SystemIcon` shows me Windows8 icon?

My code:

```
//MessageBoxIcon
XtraMessageBox.Show(errText, errCaption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

//SystemIcon
imgError.Image = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap();
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560493/messagebox-show-custom-icon this should help you out. It has a similar problem mentioned in it. one of the answer points to this snippet. https://pastebin.com/m8evBmZi.

Comment: OK, I get it now. Unfortunately I would like to leave MessageBoxIcon untouched so I was hoping to get that image and put it on my custom form, not to make my custom messagebox icon. Thank you very much.