# How to add gif in message box?

Tags: c#, image

Is there anyway I can include a gif into a message box?
This is my current code:

```
private void GameOver()
    {
        clock.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.lose + "Your time taken is " + duration/1000 + " seconds. Bye Bye", "Game Over");
        this.Close();
    }
```

Obviously the "Properties.Resources.lose" doesn't work so I'm not all too sure on where else to put.

Comment: No, you would need your own dialog form if you want more than the basic msgbox options, E.g. [How to create a custom MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox)

Comment: `Messagebox` is a very limited system, and its icons are determined by an enum. It is not customisable like that. As Alex K. said, you'll have to simply make your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MessageBox.Show() Custom Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560493/messagebox-show-custom-icon)